# Gel Strength of water

Tags: flow-control

I have been checking for the 10 seconds and 10 minutes gel Strength of water but has not seen any reasonable answer anywhere or maybe I have but don't understand.

Comment: Why do you think water is a substance *has* a gel strength?

Comment: Please add the context in which this data is used, and where you found this terminology.